# Is calling c function from lua faster than from c?

Tags: c, function, lua

Im kind of new to lua (well, I actually learned basic lua and how to use lua from c), and I am working on a simple tetris game using lua in c. (it sounds weird, but just for practice :D)

And I have a few questions:

1. I was wondering if calling c function from lua is faster.
2. if Q1 is yes, is it ok to call drawing functions in c from lua? 
   Doesn't it cause any slow down in my program?
3. What is the recommended Lua_C programming (just my way to call the program that uses lua as a script language) structure?

Ex) what kind of code should be written in Lua? What kind of code should be written in C? (drawing code, logic code, and etc.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Simple answer: No. It won't be faster. There is going to be some overhead related to the function call from Lua to C.
2. Calling the drawing function is okay, since the actual drawing will take a lot more time than the function call anyways.
3. The rule of thumb is usually to write the logic using a scripting language (in this case, Lua) and let C handle any performance intensive parts, such as rendering and heavy calculations. For example, you probably won't gain any performance by letting C handle the character movement and stuff like that. You could use a profiler to figure out which parts that might gain performance from a C implementation.

Comment: For 1, it depends entirely on what the C function does. Calling `math.sin` is probably much faster than writing a sin function in Lua, even if they do the same computations.

Comment: @lhf I concur with your statement, and that is pretty much what I pointed out in question number 3, but his question was if it would be faster to call a C function from Lua than directly from C. And even though my knowledge about this particular case (Lua to C) is pretty limited, that would seem crazy to me.